# Loop json in twig

Tags: json, symfony, twig

This is my controller where I am creating json data and passing it to twig file:

```
/**
 *this route is  for inserting data into datatable of modal of bootstrap
 * @Route("/pagerduty/edit_team_datatable")

 * @return Response
 */
public function edit_teble(Request $request){
    $edit = new team_details();
    $row_id = $request->query->get('row_id');
    $query= ("SELECT tr.id, GROUP_CONCAT(u.usrName SEPARATOR ',') AS team_members  FROM team_details td
                INNER JOIN team_registration tr ON tr.id=td.team_name
                INNER JOIN user u ON u.usrid=td.team_members_names
                WHERE td.team_name=$row_id
                GROUP BY td.team_name");
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch();
    // print_r($result);die;

    //return $this->render("team_display.html.twig",array('edit_table'=>$result));
    return new JsonResponse($result);
}
```

I am receiving json response in this manner where id is only "1" and  team_members is "8". So now, I want to create 8 id for 8 team members.

This is json data:

```
{"id":"21","team_members":"teja,preetham,kick,preetham,teja,meuser,kick,preetham"}
```

What I need is this format using looping:

```
{"id":"21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21","team_members":"teja,preetham,kick,preetham,teja,meuser,kick,preetham"}
```

Comment: Can you please show the twig page so it can be easier for people to help? Thanks.

Comment: my question is how to receive the json response in twig file and how to loop it in above format @Marc-André

Comment: Twig should not contain heavy data manipulation. Your best bet would be to manipulate the data before sending it to twig, in this case, you should change the data in your controller.

Comment: can u do it please i struggling from 1 week to get this right !!  my array has this result before converting it to string     ....... Array ( [id] => 14 [team_members] => meuser,kick, )...now what i need is  Array(14,meuser),(14,kick) format...

Comment: And you may want to give a look to this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp, in the Nested JSON objects. You might want to get something like `{"id":"21","team_members":{ "name" : "teja", "name" : "preetham", "name" : "kick", "name" : "preetham", "name" : "teja,meuser", "name" : "kick", "name" : "preetham"}}`

Can you show the entity for this object?

Comment: can u do it please i struggling from 1 week to get this right !!  my array has this result before converting it to string     ....... Array ( [id] => 14 [team_members] => meuser,kick, )...now what i need is  Array(14,meuser),(14,kick) format...  iam thinking we cannot use a loop because this data what we are getting is after executing the query i think u get it

Comment: And you may want to give a look to this: w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp, in the Nested JSON objects. You might want to get something like {"id":"21","team_members":{ "name" : "teja", "name" : "preetham", "name" : "kick", "name" : "preetham", "name" : "teja,meuser", "name" : "kick", "name" : "preetham"}} ... yes in the same way but i needed each id for each name  {"id":"21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21","team_members":"teja,preetham,kick,preetham,teja,meuser,kick,preetham"}  like this  i think this is possible by some looping  highly appreciated by your answer @Marc-André

Comment: the result which i have posted is the json data after the query exection . so i need to pass the json data to twig where i need to update id's for that i need to generate multiple id's . so i need to the above format  i hope u will get this .**

can u please post the answer for how to loop this json data using for loop in twig file to change {"id":"21","team_members":"teja,preetham,kick,preetham,teja,meuser,kick,preetham"}

this to 

 {"id":"21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21","team_members":"teja,preetham,kick,preetham,teja,meuser,kick,preetham"}

Comment: Please see @pew007 answer below. His answer is clean and should answer your needs for the data format.

Comment: Wow. You're not using any coding style I'm aware of. You violate the MVC pattern. You bypass the ORM by querying the database directly. Please delve deep into Clean Code guidelines, PSR-2 and the basic foundations of the Symfony framework. It will make your code much more readable and a lot less error-prone.

Comment: you want me to pass all the queries into modal not in the controller is it right???!@YetiCGN

Answer (score 2):

As @Marc_Andre mentioned in the comment above, you should manipulate your data in the controller instead of in the template.

Based on the format of your query result, you can do the following in the controller:

```
$formatted = [];
$id = $result['id'];
foreach ($result['team_members'] as $member) {
    $formatted[] = [$id => $member];
}

return new JsonResponse($formatted);
```